# Sequentially removing items in a 2D array on a position's row and column, starting from the center

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having another problem in my Bejeweled clone. I want to make Star Gems act like they do in Bejeweled 3, meaning they destroy gems outward from the star gem(the center). So, say the star gem was at (4, 4) in a 10x10 2D array; it would destroy the positions (3, 4), (5, 4), (4, 3) and (4, 5) first, then, say, 10 frames later, destroy (2, 4), (6, 4), (4, 2), and (4, 6), and so on.

Right now I have the `StarDestruction()` method storing the position of the star gem to a couple of Board-scope variables, and the positions to destroy in a `List<Gem>`, like so:

```
Board.starPosX = i;
Board.starPosY = j;
for (int x = 0; x < gems.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    moveTimer = 0;
    int k = x;
    int m = x;
    int q = x;
    int n = x;
    if (i - k < 0) k = 0;
    if (i + m > gems.GetLength(0) - 1) m = 0;
    if (j - q < 0) q = 0;
    if (j + n > gems.GetLength(1) - 1) n = 0;
    gemQ.Add(gems[i - k, j]);
    gemQ.Add(gems[i + m, j]);
    gemQ.Add(gems[i, j - q]);
    gemQ.Add(gems[i, j + n]);
}
```

where `gemQ` is the `List<Gem>` and gems is the 2D Gem array.

This is how I currently destroy the gems, in `Update()`:

```
foreach (Gem g in gemQ)
{
    if (timer2 % 12 == 0)
        g.KillGem(gems[starPosX, starPosY]);
}
```

where `timer2` is the timer for destroying the gems.

I have a bit simpler code for the original gem destroying, but it didn't seem to work any differently than this version. Here's the simpler code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < gems.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    if (x != i)
    {
        gems[x, j].KillGem(gems[i, j]);
    }
    if (x != j)
    {
        gems[i, x].KillGem(gems[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete edit of my reply, based on our conversation in the comments.

I understand now that:

> You want the star gem to destroy all other gems in the same column and same row as the star gem.
>   You want four gems to be destroyed at a time, with a delay between each four.
>   The explosion should move outward from the star gem, i.e. destroying the closest gems first.

Your foreach uses the time like this:

```
Timer % 12 == 0
```

At the time that is true for one gem, its true for all of them typically.  You don't want to stall between destructions either, otherwise the destruction won't get rendered or the game will visibly lag.

The second issue is that even if you did space out the destruction of the gems, you'll likely find that the destruction occurs in a spiral, instead of four at a time.

With these points in mind, you'll need to do this instead:

```
// The initial destroy gem code
var gemsToDestroy = new List<Gem>();
for (int x = 0; x < gems.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    if (x != i)
    {
        gemsToDestroy.add(gems[x, j]);
    }
    if (x != j)
    {
        gemsToDestroy.add(gems[i, x]);
    }
}

// You can change your for loop above to achieve this directly, but this is the idea
// We are putting them in order of closest first.
gemsToDestroy = gemsToDestroy.OrderBy(o => o.DistanceFromStar).ToList();

// Your periodic UPDATE code - This is pseudo code but should convey the general idea
// I've been very lazy with my use of LINQ here, you should refactor this solution to 
// to remove as many iterations of the list as possible.
if (gemsToDestroy.Any() && timer.Ready)
{
    var closestDistance = gemsToDestroy[0].DistanceFromStar;

    foreach (var gem in gemsToDestroy.Where(gem => gem.DistanceFromStar == closestDistance))
    {
        gem.Destroy();
    }

    // Again you can do this without LINQ, point is I've removed the now destroyed gems from the list
    gemsToDestroy = gemsToDestroy.Where(gem => gem.DistanceFromStar != closestDistance).ToList();

    timer.Reset(); // So that we wait X time before destroying the next set
}
```

Don't forget to prevent player input while there are items in the gemsToDestroy list and also to stop the game timer while destroying, so that the player isn't penalised time for playing well.

Comment: I actually put almost exactly what you put here in the question, near the bottom. What I want it to do is destroy them not all at the same time. If I've missed something here please tell me. And yeah, Star gems do what you said they do. Though they(like I said above) don't destroy all the gems at once.

Comment: You haven't specifically described what it's doing that you don't like, but based on your code I'm going to assume that they're being destroyed in a random order as opposed to an attractive outward explosion?

Or is it that they still look like they're exploding instantly?  If that's the case, have you tried extending the duration on your timer?  Are you expecting 4 gems to be destroyed at once, each timer tick, moving outward in all directions from the star?

Comment: Right now they still appear to be destroyed instantly. The timer in the foreach loop doesn't actually do anything except delay the destruction of all the gems. I also tried making a new variable in the Gem class, `framesUntilDeath`, then setting that in `KillGem()`, with a parameter added to increase that variable the farther it gets from the center. This hasn't worked either, but I'm probably doing it wrong. And yes, I'm expecting 4 gems to be destroyed at once, every 10 or 15 frames, moving outward.

Comment: Ok cool.  So there's a few things you're experiencing and I'll wrap them up in a edit of my post.

Comment: Hmm... It appears as though I'm going to have to move the gemsToDestroy to the Gem class... It errored at me when I tried to detonate two star gems simultaneously. When I moved it to the Gem class, however, it seems that it doesn't do much. I can see why this would work, but it doesn't appear to be. I'll experiment a little and see what I can do.

Comment: Ok. To be honest, it appears you'll likely be fighting yourself because your code isn't as object oriented as it could be.  You should think about making Gems POCOs (basic objects that just store their own state) and having a GemManager class who's purpose it is to apply deletes, manage the grid, etc.  It'll make it easier to keep track of what's going on as well as give you more power in the future.

Comment: I got it to work. It was just a matter of moving the section that starts with the orderby to `Gem.Update()`. Thank you so much! :)